# What are the exact reasons `grep` on /proc and raw disks is a bad idea?

Tags: linux, filesystems, grep

I ran `grep -r "searchphrase" /` today and that did not work. I did some research and found `find / -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H "searchphrase"` to be the right approach.

I gather `/proc` and disks like `/dev/sda1` are culprits for a non-successful grep.

I would love some deep technical background on the "why". I think that some links within `/proc` create infinite loops when traversed, and I read there are more reasons, but nothing specific.

Also, what happens when a raw disk is grepped? Can the binary data (that is accessible on `/dev/sda1`, as far as I know?) not be interpreted, as only a `mount` with a filesystem-type makes the data from the disk intelligible? Would it therefore still be possible to grep for a binary string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can `grep` `/dev/sda1` and `/proc` but you probably don't want to.  In more detail:

1. Yes, you can run grep the binary contents of `/dev/sda1`.  But, with modern large hard disks, this will take a very long time and the result is not likely to be useful.
2. Yes, you can grep the contents of `/proc` but be aware that your computer's memory is mapped in there as files.  On a modern computer with gigabytes of RAM, this will take a long time to grep and, again, the result is not likely to be useful.

As an exception, if you are looking for data on a hard disk with a damaged file system, you might run `grep something /dev/sda1` as part of an attempt to recover the file's data.

#### Other problematic files in `/dev`

The hard disks and hard disk partitions under `/dev` can be, if one has enough patience, grepped.  Other files (hat tip: [user2313067](https://superuser.com/users/221021/user2313067)), however, may cause problems:

1. `/dev/zero` is a file of infinite length.  Fortunately, `grep` (at least the GNU version) is smart enough to skip it:

   ```
   $ grep something /dev/zero
   grep: input is too large to count
   ```
2. `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` are also infinite.   The command `grep something /dev/random` will run forever unless `grep` is signaled to stop.

   It can be useful to grep `/dev/urandom` when generating passwords.  To get, for example, five random alphanumeric characters:

   ```
   $ grep --text -o '[[:alnum:]]' /dev/urandom | head -c 10
   G
   4
   n
   X
   2
   ```

   This is not infinite because, after it has received enough characters, `head` closes the pipe causing grep to terminate.

#### Infinite loops

> *"...links ... create infinite loops when traversed..."*

Grep (at least the GNU version) is smart enough not to do that.  Let's consider two cases:

1. With the `-r` option, grep *does not* follow symbolic links unless they are explicitly specified on the command line.  Hence, infinite loops are not possible.
2. With the `-R` option, grep *does* follow symbolic links but it checks them and refuses to get caught in a loop.  To illustrate:

   ```
   $ mkdir a
   $ ln -s ../ a/b
   $ grep -R something .
   grep: warning: ./a/b: recursive directory loop
   ```

#### Excluding problematic directories from `grep -r`

As an aside, `grep` provides a limited facility to stop grep from searching certain files or directories.  For example, you can exclude all directories named `proc`, `sys`, and `dev` from grep's recursive search with:

```
grep --exclude-dir proc --exclude-dir sys --exclude-dir dev -r something /
```

Alternatively, we can exclude `proc`, `sys`, and `dev` using bash's extended globs:

```
shopt -s extglob
grep -r something /!(proc|sys|dev)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a great answer. Unless another hero emerges out of the dark tonight I will accept it tomorrow!
I'm wondering about one more thing, and I hope it's not too far out: If `grep` searches a file in `/proc` that leads to mapped memory, could it happen that `grep` hits an EOF inside the (random) memory, and interprets the following data as a new filename to search? I've started reading the `grep` source code, but I guess I won't see too much in it.

Comment: @krork In some old operating systems, like CP/M, the end of a file was signaled by the EOF character.  Because modern file systems keep track of the size of a file, such characters have fallen out of use.

Comment: Grepping `/dev` may well never end as grep starts to scan `/dev/zero` or similar. Unsure if such files exist in `/proc` or `/sys`.

Comment: @user2313067 Good point!  While GNU grep will refuse to search `/dev/zero`, it will search `/dev/random` forever unless stopped.  Answer updated.

Comment: I don't do much with /proc or /sys, but since these are virtual directories which may be updated at any time, you might get unexpected/unrepeatable results from multiple runs. Of course, this can happen with regular file systems too, but it might be a bit more surprising here.